# Exception executing consequence for rule "XXX" in com.sample: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "112E.112E22" while executing rule

Tags: drools

I am getting the following exception while executing the rule. (only in rare cases). 
Am using drools 5.5.

Exception executing consequence for rule "XXX" in com.sample: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "112E.112E22"

Any one is familiar with the above issue ? Kindly help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with this issue. And looking at this string, it's rather evident that it isn't a number according to Java syntax.

Comment: Hi laune, Sometimes am getting this above exception and Sometimes am getting Exception executing consequence for rule "XXX" in com.sample: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "".  Have you solved the issue ?

Comment: Yes, I fixed the bug.

Comment: Hi laune, Thanks for reply.Can you kindly explain how to solve the issue ?

Comment: I don't have your code - what do you expect me to explain?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience laune, Added the rule which i got the issue.

Comment: An edit was registered 9 hrs ago, but its effect doesn't show.